# jQuery Content Slider with Scrolling (pic attached)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have looked through dozens and dozens of sliders but can't find the one I need. I am trying to match the one in the picture below (an artist mock up). Does anyone know a jQuery slider that can do this?

[image]

The closest one I found is below, but it is still missing the look and scroll:
http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/featured-content-slider/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: lol where is that 1st one from? i cant see the functionality in an image

Comment: The demo you linked just looks like the image you provided, just another layout. As this is a screenshot I don't know about the functionality.

Comment: Have you tried... I don't know... making it ?

Comment: I think he is asking for the scroll buttons on the top and bottom of the list of graph names on the right (But it took me a second to figure that out if that is it too :))

Comment: I'd honestly just use the cycle plug-in and add/extend functionality to do the scrollbars.  That's not what you wanted to hear, but meh.  If I get the time, maybe tonight I'll try it and post an answer.

Comment: The image is a mock up. I have to find a slider that works based on what the artist drew up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one,
http://jqueryglobe.com/labs/feature_list/

If you tell me where you found that one I can tell you the name instantly.

Comment: Thanks for this. I started another question about how to modify it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657229/how-to-modify-this-jquery-plugin-slider-for-scrolling-and-orientation