# How to modify this jQuery plugin slider for scrolling and orientation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I found a jQuery slider plugin that does almost what I need. I need to change the tabs so it is on the right side (by adding an option). Also, I would like to add scrolling to the tabs in case there is more than 3 tabs (also by an option). I am trying to make it look like this which is an artist mock up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR8RY.png

This is the script I am trying to modify with the code below it:
http://jqueryglobe.com/labs/feature_list/

```
/*
 * FeatureList - simple and easy creation of an interactive "Featured Items" widget
 * Examples and documentation at: http://jqueryglobe.com/article/feature_list/
 * Version: 1.0.0 (01/09/2009)
 * Copyright (c) 2009 jQueryGlobe
 * Licensed under the MIT License: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License
 * Requires: jQuery v1.3+
*/
;(function($) {
    $.fn.featureList = function(options) {
        var tabs    = $(this);
        var output  = $(options.output);

        new jQuery.featureList(tabs, output, options);

        return this;    
    };

    $.featureList = function(tabs, output, options) {
        function slide(nr) {
            if (typeof nr == "undefined") {
                nr = visible_item + 1;
                nr = nr >= total_items ? 0 : nr;
            }

            tabs.removeClass('current').filter(":eq(" + nr + ")").addClass('current');

            output.stop(true, true).filter(":visible").fadeOut();
            output.filter(":eq(" + nr + ")").fadeIn(function() {
                visible_item = nr;  
            });
        }

        var options         = options || {}; 
        var total_items     = tabs.length;
        var visible_item    = options.start_item || 0;

        options.pause_on_hover      = options.pause_on_hover        || true;
        options.transition_interval = options.transition_interval   || 5000;

        output.hide().eq( visible_item ).show();
        tabs.eq( visible_item ).addClass('current');

        tabs.click(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('current')) {
                return false;   
            }

            slide( tabs.index( this) );
        });

        if (options.transition_interval > 0) {
            var timer = setInterval(function () {
                slide();
            }, options.transition_interval);

            if (options.pause_on_hover) {
                tabs.mouseenter(function() {
                    clearInterval( timer );

                }).mouseleave(function() {
                    clearInterval( timer );
                    timer = setInterval(function () {
                        slide();
                    }, options.transition_interval);
                });
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This is the CSS:

```
body {
    background: #EEE;   
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

#content {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #FFF;   
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

hr {
    border: none;
    height: 1px; line-height: 1px;
    background: #CCC;   
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 7px 0;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    line-height: 1px;
    font-size: 1px;
}

a { 
    outline-color: #888;    
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9tgdK/2/

I set up a jsfiddle to play with.  Should help anyone willing willing to try.  I have some ideas.  I'll post an answer if I figure it out.

@TruMan1, do you want it to scroll when you hover over the scroll, or just click?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9tgdK/4/

That is a jsfiddle that uses the jQuery cycle plugin to achieve the same effect as the one you are using.  The cycle plugin is MUCH more developed than this featureList thing.  I'm racking my brain trying to figure out the scrollbars.  I'll post if I think of something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer: [jsFiddle: features box that slides and scrolls](http://jsfiddle.net/9tgdK/12/)**

**Features:**

- Slides over time
- Click next and previous
- Support for lots of slides
- Smooth scrolling
- Move to item on click
- Stop movement on hover
- Easily extended because it uses the cycle plug-in.

Time spent on project: **4hrs**

Comment: <s>Um... you can't click on them?</s> oh, you click the arrows.

Comment: You can now click on them, and it doesn't scroll when your mouse is hovering over the pager.

Comment: Wierd thing happens when you click the top one.

Comment: Wow thanks for this! I loved how you leveraged the famous cycle plugin to do this. It's brilliant!! I also extended the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662998/help-refactor-this-jquery-cycle-extension

Answer (score 1):

Ok, no fancy scrollbars or anything, but it will iterate through each one bringing it to the top index. I spent ages getting this working properly.
You can test it by adding additional items to the Lists.

```
/*
 * FeatureList - simple and easy creation of an interactive "Featured Items" widget
 * Examples and documentation at: http://jqueryglobe.com/article/feature_list/
 * Version: 1.0.0 (01/09/2009)
 * Copyright (c) 2009 jQueryGlobe
 * Licensed under the MIT License: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License
 * Requires: jQuery v1.3+
*/
;(function($) {
    $.fn.featureList = function(options) {
        var tabs    = $(this);
        var output  = $(options.output);

        new jQuery.featureList(tabs, output, options);

        return this;    
    };

    $.featureList = function(tabs, output, options) 
    {
        function slide(nr) {
            if (typeof nr == "undefined") {
                nr = visible_item + 1;
                nr = nr >= total_items ? 0 : nr;
            }

            tabs.removeClass('current').filter(":eq(" + nr + ")").addClass('current');

            output.stop(true, true).filter(":visible").fadeOut();
            output.filter(":eq(" + nr + ")").fadeIn(function() {
                visible_item = nr;  
            });

            $(tabs[(nr - 1 + total_items) % total_items]).parent().slideUp(500,function(){
                var order = "";
                for(var i = total_items; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    var nextInd = ((nr - 1) + i) % total_items;
                    var tab = $(tabs[nextInd]);
                    if(i == total_items)
                        tab.parent().slideDown(500);
                    tab.parent().prependTo(tab.parent().parent());
                    order += nextInd + ", ";
                }
            });
        }

        var options         = options || {}; 
        var total_items     = tabs.length;
        var visible_item    = options.start_item || 0;

        options.pause_on_hover      = options.pause_on_hover        || true;
        options.transition_interval = options.transition_interval   || 2000;

        output.hide().eq( visible_item ).show();
        tabs.eq( visible_item ).addClass('current');

        tabs.click(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('current')) {
                return false;   
            }
            slide( tabs.index( this) );
        });

        if (options.transition_interval > 0) {
            var timer = setInterval(function () {
                slide();
            }, options.transition_interval);

            if (options.pause_on_hover) {
                tabs.mouseenter(function() {
                    clearInterval( timer );

                }).mouseleave(function() {
                    clearInterval( timer );
                    timer = setInterval(function () {
                        slide();
                    }, options.transition_interval);
                });
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ugh... I don't think that's a helpful implementation at all.  What if the user wants to click on any, not just the currently viewable ones?

Comment: You can still click on any of them and they get focused, trust me, it's good.

Comment: I tested it out, mate, you can only click on visible ones. I understand you can just click the bottom one and it will scroll.  Also, your animations don't look very classy.  Try and find some way to use animate instead of fades?  That'd help it a bit.

Comment: I just didnt want to spend 4 hours on it so I did it as fast as I could.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the height of the box simply change the height of `div#feature_list` and to add additional items simply add an additional `li` item in both the `ul`'s within `feature_list`

Comment: he wants it to scroll, mate, not get bigger :)