# Help refactor this jQuery Cycle extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I had someone help extend the jQuery Cycle plugin and works great (thanks Levi Morrison!). It was a quick prototype so it still has a few quirks:

http://jsfiddle.net/9tgdK/12/

Scrolling up gives a weird effect and can not get it to work properly. Another thing is that it does not pause when you hover over the main content image. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer: [featurebox v2](http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/qytuT/)** *[(view fullscreen)](http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/qytuT/embedded/result/)*

I use a new technique for this version, and it's a lot cleaner.  I think it does what you want.

**Edit:** no longer assumes all pager tabs are the same height.  Runs slightly faster.

Comment: I discovered a bug on scroll up.  Working on it.

Comment: Bug fixed, code is MUCH cleaner.  Enjoy!

Comment: Found more optimizations.  Hang on.

Comment: Added one more optimization to stop animations from building up.  This happened when you clicked on next a bunch of times.

Comment: Wow very clean and elegant! Thanks!!